# Function breaking jquery on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, compatibility

So i use this function()

```
months = months.filter(function(e, p) { return months.indexOf(e) == p; });
```

and a test `alert();` works only before it. If i put the alert() somewhere below this function it does not work anymore... 
This only happens in IE, in Chrome it is fine. This breaks every jquery below it. You can see the problem live [Here](http://bit.ly/16xI0yV)

Also, a direct link to the js file is [Here](http://bit.ly/10nPVxX)

This function is there to filter the repeated `months` get from all `data-mes` attributes on li on this page... I have no idea why this is happening, also, i am using this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

but, aparently has no effect in this problem....

Here is the full code of this problem:

```
// gets all `data-mes` into an array
var months = $('#gride li').map(function() { return $(this).data('mes'); }).get();

// remove repeated meses
months = months.filter(function(e, p) { return months.indexOf(e) == p; });

// sorts the months
var order = ['janeiro','fevereiro','março','abril','maio','junho','julho','agosto','setembro','outubro','novembro','dezembro'];
orderedMonths = months.sort(function(a,b){ return order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b); });

// add them, ordered, to the <select> with id #selectMes
$.each(orderedMonths, function(_, v) {
    $('#selectmes').append($('<li class="filter" data-filter="'+ v +'">').val(v).text(v));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery **[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)**

```
months = months.filter(function(e, p) { return $.inArray(e, months) == p });
```

**[Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** not supported below IE9.

You have an issue with array.filter as well, since filter will not work in IE9 below, instead use [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
 months = $.grep(months,function(e, p) { return $.inArray(e, months) == p });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p6aab/)**

Comment: I edited the question with the full js of this part, if you could pls take a look

Comment: @user1576978 By any chance what error are you getting? try this `months.filter(function(e, p, arr) { return $.inArray(e, arr) == p });`

Comment: well, acctually i had to change 2 lines that had indexOf(), so maybe i did something wrong, here is how i did:http://jsfiddle.net/pT3Sm/

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(months))` and paste it here

Comment: ["julho","julho","junho","junho","junho","junho"]

Comment: @user1576978 Your issue is with filter.. Thats the error you are geting right?

Comment: Yeah that is it, thank you. Is there anywhere I can find a index of js IE problems? I say that because aparenttly I have a couple more in my code, but not concerning this question

Comment: @user1576978 You are welcome. i did not quite understand what do you mean by `Is there anywhere I can find a index of js IE problems?`

Comment: I mean something like a table that tells me which functions I should avoid using because of IE compatibility problems (like indexOf() to inArray() )

Comment: Let me find out. I will comment here once I have the link

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` does not work well with IE. Write your own, or since you already have jQuery in your webpage. Use jQuery method:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Thanks.. I'm reading about inArray() right now, is it possible for you to help me 'convert' the month = line to inArray() instead of indexOf ?

Answer (score 0):

indexOf is not available in many versions if IE. Check out jQuery's inArray instead: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/